# PHP, remove from array?

Tags: php

Im searching through an array of countries to see if any match the UK, if so I pull it out and put it at the top of my drop down.

```
foreach($this->registry->stockistCountries as $value)
{
    if($value['country'] == 'UK'){
        $buffer .= '<option>UK</option>';
        $buffer .= '<option disabled>------------------</option>';
    }

}
```

I was wondering, if UK is found, is there a way to remove it from the array $this->registry->stockistCountries?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your loop to:

```
foreach($this->registry->stockistCountries as $i => $value)
{
    if($value['country'] == 'UK'){
        $buffer .= '<option>UK</option>';
        $buffer .= '<option disabled>------------------</option>';
        unset($this->registry->stockistCountries[$i]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

just change your [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)-loop to also get the key and then just use [`unset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php):

```
foreach($this->registry->stockistCountries as $key => $value){
                                  // add this ^^^^^^^^
  // do something
  if(/* whatever */){
    unset($this->registry->stockistCountries[$key]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like
`@unset($this->registry->stocklist['country']['UK']);`

Comment: If this case you don't need to run foreach()

Answer (score 0):

```
$found = array_search('UK', $this->registry->stockistCountries); //search for UK


unset($this->registry->stockistCountries[$found]); // Remove from array
```